# get the value of $scope.data in a variable in same controlled

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

My code is some thing

```
        $scope.data = {};
        var init = function () {
            $http.post('views/Report.aspx/GetMailReport', {})
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.data = JSON.parse(data.d);
            })
            .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.data = status;
            })
        };
        init();

        var data = $scope.data;
```

But the var data is returning empty {}

Comment: This happens because $http.post is asynchronic, your logic should happen within success and error functinos or by nesting the promises. Easier way here would be to call a function in those two places

Comment: Thanks a lot.. for helping me out.. full day wasted for the same simple thing

Answer (score 0):

If you want a copy you should do as below... As the http call is asynchronous you assign inside the success callback method

```
$scope.data = {}; 
var data;

var init = function () {           
  $http.post('views/Report.aspx/GetMailReport', {}) .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
  $scope.data = JSON.parse(data.d); 
data = $scope.data;
}) .error(function (data, status, headers, config) { 
  $scope.data = status; 
}) }; 
init();
```

Edited:
Here is the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/paila/euvku0b6/) to a fiddle that I have created.

Comment: have tryed the same before... doing so data is returning empty null

Comment: firebug will never say lie... i tryed <div>{{data}}</div> also.. returns json string

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or plunker with your problem?

Comment: Create a fiddle. Let me know if it helps?

Comment: I have created one fiddle already and updated the answer... see if it helps