# Get the data in a html attributes angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am trying some thing like this but shows `Error: [$parse:syntax]`

```
  <div ng-init="myData={{data}}"></div>
```

Need help i am fresher in angular

Comment: hear data is json type data

Answer (score 0):

You should try Removing curly braces.

If you want a copy you should do as below... As the http call is asynchronous you assign inside the success callback method

```
$scope.data = {}; 
var data;

var init = function () {           
  $http.post('views/Report.aspx/GetMailReport', {}) .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
  $scope.data = JSON.parse(data.d); 
data = $scope.data;
}) .error(function (data, status, headers, config) { 
  $scope.data = status; 
}) }; 
init();
```

Edited:
Here is the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/paila/euvku0b6/) to a fiddle that I have created.

Comment: data is a array of json data... retrived from a controlled... removing curly braces will treat as normal string of data.. just 'data'

Comment: Using curly braces will interpolate the data and treat as string... So you do not need curly braces if you want to read json array object and initialize it to myData... If that is not what you are looking for... Need more info on what are you trying to achieve by i initializing

Comment: thanks srinivas.. this was my first question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26572610/get-the-value-of-scope-data-in-a-variable-in-same-controlled?noredirect=1#comment41763151_26572610)
but i was unsuccessful so i was trying this method

Comment: I have tryed the same before... doing so data is returning empty null

Comment: Create a fiddle. Let me know if it helps?